# Nullable Enum values don't show in intellisense or design view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums, custom-controls, intellisense

I am developing a custom user control. The user control has a property that maps to an enumeration and should not have any default value, i.e. the consumer of the control MUST set it.

**The property:**

```
<Description("This is the property description"),
Category("SomeCategory"), Bindable(True)>
Public Property SomeProperty As Enumerations.SomeEnumeration?
```

**The enumeration:**

```
Namespace Enumerations
    Public Enum SomeEnumeration
        Zero = 0
        One
        Two
    End Enum
End Namespace
```

**The check:**

```
If SomeProperty Is Nothing Then
    Throw New ApplicationException("You must set SomeProperty.")
End If
```

**The problem:**

All of the logic works. My problem is that none of the enumeration values show up in intellisense when you try to set `SomeProperty` **from markup**. A colleague of mine found [this related support request](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760202/nullable-enumeration-types-dont-get-intellisense-auto-complete), so it appears to be a known issue.

My question is, what is the best way to support all of the behaviors I need on this control, as well as keep intellisense on this property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could recreate this issue - making an enumeration nullable makes the intellisense stop working. I guess this is because nullable types are objects.

Suggest keeping the enumeration as NOT nullable. Have a default value of `NotSet` or `None`. If the enumeration is not set, you could throw an exception in your getter or initialization code.

Property

```
<Description("This is the property description"),
Category("SomeCategory"), Bindable(True)>
Public Property SomeProperty As Enumerations.SomeEnumeration
```

Enumeration

```
Namespace Enumerations
    Public Enum SomeEnumeration
        NotSet = -1
        Zero = 0
        One
        Two
    End Enum
End Namespace
```

Check

```
If SomeProperty Is SomeProperty.NotSet Then
    Throw New ApplicationException("You must set SomeProperty.")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Enum SomeEnumeration
    NotSet = -1
    Zero = 0
    One
    Two
End Enum
```

Default value of enum is 0, so if you declare variable of SomeEnumeration, defaul value of that variable will be Zero. 
 e.g; 
     SomeEnumeration SomeProperty;

value of SomeProperty will be SomeEnumeration.Zero